# Variable declaration in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm just beginning to learn Dart and Flutter and I was wondering if there is any difference in the following declarations?

`final List<WordPair> _suggestions = <WordPair>[];`

and

`final _suggestions = <WordPair>[];`

They both seem to exhibit the same behaviour but I'm wondering if there is some underlying difference?

I prefer the first declaration as I'm coming from a C/C++ back ground

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference between them at all.
The second syntax is here only to avoid pointless repetition.

Usually you should prefer the shorthand in Dart.  [According to the DO/DON'T of dart](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/design#consider-type-annotating-private-fields-and-top-level-variables-if-the-type-isnt-obvious),  there are some conditions in which you'll want to use the full syntax though.

```
 final List<Foo> globalVariable = <Foo>[];


 void func() {
   final localVariable = <Foo>[]
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link :)